# Is it possible to set a maximum number of bytes on NodeJS's net 'data' event?

Tags: node.js, networking, tcp, max

I'm parsing chunks of a TCP byte stream using the net module. Each time the 'data' event is called I'm handed a variable containing an unknown number of bytes -- sometimes up to 22k. Is there a way to specify that I'd only like to work with blocks of up to, say, 1024 bytes?

Comment: Why not just split it up yourself? http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_slice_start_end

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this.  The network stream is using streams and buffers underneath and it will generally manage this "on its own".

Comment: When data comes in, there's no guarantee that the bytes received will contain an entire object to unpack. Likewise, they might include a few of the first bytes from the next object. In either case, I'm holding over some bytes for the next 'data' event. When I get those bytes, I now have two buffers -- the holdovers and the new bytes. I have to merge them somehow to prevent trying to read a 4 byte integer that lives on the cusp. Concatenating the two buffers into a newly allocated one is a huge performance hit when the buffers can be dozens of kb at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NodeJS v0.10.0](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/) introduced an improved Streams API which included support for a 'readable' event and the ability to request a given number of bytes from the stream.